# chef refresh automatic attribute without a chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, devops

I'd like refresh the automatic attributes on nodes e.g. the `.filesystem` attribute to get disk space on nodes etc. How can I do that without running `sudo chef-client` on the nodes? `chef-client -o ...` doesn't seem to work.

For context I have nodes set up with my chef server along with roles and run lists. Running `chef-client` would run the corresponding run lists which in some cases I don't want to do (for instance I have a run list that installs and runs a docker image, I only would like to do that occasionally).

Answer (score 1):

This is not something Chef supports directly. The closest you could get without major work would be a recipe with just the code `node.save` which you then run via `-o` mode. Keep in mind this will change a lot more than just the Ohai data since all the attributes that usually come from cookbooks in the run list expansion will not be present, which is why `-o` disables the node save in the first place. More generally you could build a tool that runs Ohai and updates only that automatic level attributes, but no such script exists in Chef itself.